# How to implement Kmeans evaluator in Spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I want to select k-means model in terms of 'k' parameter based on the lowest k-means score.

I can find find optimal value of 'k' parameter by hand, writing something like

```
  def clusteringScore0(data: DataFrame, k: Int): Double = {
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler().
      setInputCols(data.columns.filter(_ != "label")).
      setOutputCol("featureVector")
    val kmeans = new KMeans().
      setSeed(Random.nextLong()).
      setK(k).
      setPredictionCol("cluster").
      setFeaturesCol("featureVector")
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler, kmeans))
    val kmeansModel = pipeline.fit(data).stages.last.asInstanceOf[KMeansModel]
    kmeansModel.computeCost(assembler.transform(data)) / data.count()   }

  (20 to 100 by 20).map(k => (k, clusteringScore0(numericOnly, k))).
    foreach(println)
```

---

#### Should I use CrossValitor API?

Something like this:

```
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(kmeansModel.k, 20 to 100 by 20).build()
val cv = new CrossValidator().setEstimator(pipeline).setEvaluator(new KMeansEvaluator()).setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid).setNumFolds(3)
```

There are Evaluators for regression and classification, but no Evaluator for clustering.

So I should implement Evaluator interface. I am stuck with `evaluate` method.

```
class KMeansEvaluator extends Evaluator {
  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Evaluator = defaultCopy(extra)

  override def evaluate(data: Dataset[_]): Double = ??? // should I somehow adapt code from KMeansModel.computeCost()?
  override val uid = Identifiable.randomUID("cost_evaluator")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Hi `ClusteringEvaluator`  is available from Spark 2.3.0. You can use to find optimal k values by including ClusteringEvaluator object into your for-loop. You can also find more detail for silhouette analysis in [Scikit-learn page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html). In short, the score should be between [-1,1], the larger score is the better. I have modified a for loop below for your codes.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator
val evaluator = new ClusteringEvaluator()
        .setFeaturesCol("featureVector")
        .setPredictionCol("cluster")
        .setMetricName("silhouette")

for(k <- 20 to 100 by 20){
    clusteringScore0(numericOnly,k)

    val transformedDF = kmeansModel.transform(numericOnly)

    val score = evaluator.evaluate(transformedDF)

    println(k,score,kmeansModel.computeCost(transformedDF))
}
```